# Hamcrest containsInAnyOrder match if string contains

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

Let's say I have

```
@Test
public void iterable_matches_order () {

    List<String> cloths = Lists.newArrayList("shirts", "shoes", "pants", "socks");

    assertThat(cloths, containsInAnyOrder("shi", "sho", "pan", "soc"));
}
```

I want this to pass because `shi` is contained in `shirts`, `sho` is contained in `shoes` and so on. `containsInAnyOrder` seems to pass only when each entry is an exact match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation: http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#containsInAnyOrder(T...) it doesn't match substring, but rather whole string

`assertThat(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"), containsInAnyOrder("bar", "foo"))`

Comment: Ya, the word `contains` is very misleading here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the below, but unfortunately you can check only one substring at a time. You will have to have multiple asserts since you will not know which substring failed in the list.

assertThat(cloths, hasItem(contains("shi")))

Answer (score 0):

By default `containsInAnyOrder` matches the given elements via the equals method. But you can provide arbitrary submatchers. In your example you can use the `Matchers.containsString` method:

```
assertThat(cloths, containsInAnyOrder(containsString("shi"), containsString("sho"),
    containsString("pan"), containsString("soc")));
```

Beware that the above assertion will also by successful if you reorder the items in `cloths`. If order matters use `Matchers.contains`:

```
assertThat(cloths, contains(containsString("shi"), containsString("sho"),
    containsString("pan"), containsString("soc")));
```